# why this.close() close application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

I have a window in wpf that i want on the escape button to close the window. So i wrotethis code on PreviewKeyDown event, but it closes the entire application, including the main window and current window. I just want to close current window.

```
 //this code for open second window
 private void M_Mahale_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Tanzimat.MahaleWin Mahale = new Tanzimat.MahaleWin();
        Mahale.ShowDialog();
    }
  //this code for PreviewKeyDown event on second window and current window
 private void Window_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Escape)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have this same code in the main window by chance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, based on this comment `//this code for PreviewKeyDown event on second window and current window` you have the same code in both windows in the `PreviewKeyDown` -so in both windows change the code to this:

```
private void Window_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Escape)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

and that will keep other windows from getting the event when it's been handled already. See, what's happening is when the escape key is pressed both windows are getting the message, and you didn't tell the main window (i.e. the one behind the current one) **not to process it.**

Comment: +1 This seems to be the only answer that takes the actual question into account properly.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, thanks a lot! That means something coming from you my friend!

Comment: ok thanks it works.what is the deference between KeyDown and PreviewKeyDown

Answer (score 1):

You window has a name `Mahale` and or order to close it from the main window, you should call:

```
 Mahale.Close();
```

If you call `this.Close();` in main form it is quite natural for the program to exit

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.Hide() to hide that window, but that window still exists.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to achieve your goal is using of Button's IsCancel property.

> You can set the IsCancel property on the Cancel button to true,
>   causing the Cancel button to automatically close the dialog without
>   handling the Click event.

See [here](http://wpf.2000things.com/tag/iscancel/) for examples.

Answer (score -1):

do :

```
private void Window_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Escape)
    {
        this.Hide();
    }
}
```

instead.

Close() close every frames. Use hide().

Comment: "Close() close every frames", this might be incorrect. What does "frame" refer to?

Comment: Not at all, the OP wants to close the window.